# Cannot delete files outside the current working directory Grunt

Tags: gruntjs

I am using grunt to build my angular project. So it worked well, but at some point I cannot run 'grunt serve' or 'grunt build' anymore. Every time I get the following error message

> Cannot delete files outside the current working directory

The strange thing is, that I am the only one, who gets this error. All of my colleagues can build or serve without any error. Of course I found a solution for that (using '--force'), but I think this cannot be the solution as I am the only one who got this error. Can anyone please explain that error to me and maybe give be a better solution that the force-option!

```
// Empties folders to start fresh
    clean: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          dot: true,
          src: [
            '.tmp',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*',
            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git{,*/}*'
          ]
        }]
      },
      server: '.tmp'
    },
```

Comment: using --force shouldn't process the deletion, it will only continue to other tasks. Can you confirm this?
Also, what grunt plugin are you using for deletion and can you provide your gruntfile code.

Comment: yes thats true, I am going to edit my post, to show the grunt clean task, however this is the basic yeoman code without any changes.

Comment: which operating system are you on?

Comment: Could you run the task with the `-verbose` option and dump the console log here. thx

Comment: OSX newest. Going to paste the dumb in a minute

Comment: @SebastienDaniel http://pastebin.com/jsRGXh3V

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104580/discussion-between-sebastien-daniel-and-threxx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you have to use the `force` option of the task (*not the --force option of grunt*) to allow grunt-contrib-clean to delete files outside cwd.

Now, before you test this, I recommend you try it in a test environment because unlike many grunt tasks, **grunt-contrib-clean is destructive**, you've been warned.

```
clean: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      dot: true,
->    force: true,
      src: [
        '.tmp',
        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*',
        '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git{,*/}*'
      ]
    }]
  },
  server: '.tmp'
},
```

That "should" fix the error you're getting.

Comment: It didn't work for me that way, so I add 
  "options: {
    force: true
  }", right after "clean" open bracket starts.

Answer (score 5):

For the curious, this is probably caused by

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/1469

The issue is new with node 5.7, which I'm betting @threxx is using while her co-workers are still on 5.6 or earlier.

Until the PR for the issue is merged the `force` flag is a great work around.

Answer (score 3):

I edited my Gruntfile.js as follows:

```
// Empties folders to start fresh
clean: {
  options: {
    force: true
  },
  dist: {
    files: [{
      dot: true,
      src: [
        '.tmp',
        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*',
        '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git{,*/}*'
      ]
    }]
  },
  server: '.tmp'
},
```